# Is there a way to control the size of an image when using html output tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

I'm using the following code to upload an image for viewing before passing it on to my server.  I want to put constraints on the size of the image using css.  The CSS is having no effect on the image as it is rendered by output. Is there a way around this? I tried adding the CSS attribute to its surrounding div but that did not work either.

The HTML:

```
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" file-model="myFile"/>
  <output id="list" class="resize-image" alt="Image"></output>
```

The CSS:

```
#list{
  max-width: 15px;
  max-height: 7px;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
var handleFileSelect = function (evt) {//already set up for multiple files; not what i want to do.
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                // Only process image files.
                if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                    continue;
                }

                var reader = new FileReader();

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                    return function(e) {
                        // Render thumbnail.
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                    };
                })(f);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: `.list` targets and element with _class_ `list`, whereas yours has an _id_.

Comment: That is true however it has no effect. I was experimenting and forgot to change it back. Sorry about that and am editing that now.

Comment: Well you’d need to set max-width and -height for the img element, not for the container element …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The simples would be to use `height` and `width` `img` tag attributes.**

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img height="7" width="15" class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
```

If you really would like to use `.css` for this task you can use `background-size`, but then `background` property must be set with url to the image in `css`.

**You can also simply override the `img` tag in `css` like this:**

```
img{
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Here you can test both approaches : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size

Comment: _“The simples would be to use height and width img tag attributes”_ – that would possible distort the image though – at least you’d have to read the actual image dimensions, and then _calculate_ the new width/height accordingly to have it still display at its original aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you sir! That little insight was big for me. Btw, if I wanted to assign an src, is there a simple way to do that? Also, I presume your answer is in px, is there a way to do it in em? I mean is there a way to regulate this in css?

Comment: Well there is a ocean of possible ways, but if you make another question I will be happy to answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045438/working-with-html-output-tag-to-view-scalable-image-and-assign-src

Comment: @Urahara, what do you mean override the image tag? I mean, there is not img tag in the css.

Comment: `img{
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}`

Comment: This will override any image size on the site globally inserted with the <img src...

Comment: @Urahara, I understand that, thank you. The issue is that I'm not using a <img tag but rather a <output tag in my html.  The point of this post is how to do this to an image rendered with an output tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72966/discussion-between-rashadb-and-urahara).