# Working with HTML output tag to view scalable image and assign src

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes

I have the following code, which returns an image using the output attribute from HTML.  I want to be able to scale/edit this image with max-width and max-height. I also want to assign this image an SRC.

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" file-model="myFile"/>
  <output id="list" class="resize-image" alt="Image"></output>
```

My JS:

```
  var handleFileSelect = function (evt) {//already set up for multiple files; not what i want to do.
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                // Only process image files.
                if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                    continue;
                }

                var reader = new FileReader();

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                    return function(e) {
                        // Render thumbnail.
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.innerHTML = ['<img height="35" width="75" class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                    };
                })(f);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If you really want to use `css` properties in this case you have to inject them inline using `style` attribute

```
 var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img height="35" width="75" class="thumb" src="',
        e.target.result,
        'style="max-height:25px; max-width:25px;"', // You can manipulate that dynamically using 
        '" title="',
        escape(theFile.name),
        '"/>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
```

Check this for dynamic css manipulation : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_setcolor

Comment: I tried what you suggested there but that did not work it threw an error.

net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: net::ERR_INVALID_URL - means that your picture url is messed up. This is about injecting the 'style="max-height:25px; max-width:25px;" ' into your code, be very care full with " "  and ' '

Comment: Great! I got the damn thing to work as needed. I'll take a look a jQuery, it doens't look like I can do without it. Btw, how much php do I need to know to get that stuff to work. As of now, I only know pure js and much of what I do is functional though I dabble in a little express and the rest is html and css with angular. I'm a pure beginner . . .

Comment: Please level me up if the other answer was helpful, and good luck with your development! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have `.thumb{max-height:35px;max-width:75px;}` in your css, when you create the new element set the class attribute and the css will apply to that element. Also, why are you creating a span and then setting the innerHTML to an image? Why not just create the image?

**CSS**

```
.thumb{max-height:35px;max-width:75px;}
```

**Create Image**

```
var Img = document.createElement('img');
// .setAttribute(AttributeType, Attribute Value);
Img.setAttribute('class','thumb'); //Class Attribute
Img.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);//Src Attribute
document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(Img, null);
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!